# Как прописать в конкретном коде команду для автоудаления файла?

Tags: python

Всем привет, в данном коде папка (hesoyam8927163) создается после открытия приложения (написанного на py) и я хотел бы, чтобы она после этого сразу удалялась. Подскажите как можно воплотить эту идею, пока знаний не хватает для этого. Заранее всем спасибо за помощь

```
import os

def makeFolders():
    if os.path.exists(r'C:\hesoyam8927163'):
        print(0/0)
    else:
        os.makedirs(r'C:\hesoyam8927163\Chrome')
        os.makedirs(r'C:\hesoyam8927163\Opera')
        os.makedirs(r'C:\hesoyam8927163\Firefox')
        os.makedirs(r'C:\hesoyam8927163\SystemInformation')
        os.makedirs(r'C:\hesoyam8927163\TxtFilesFromDesktop')
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Answer (score 0):

Удалить пустую папку:

```
os.rmdir('путь к папке')
```

Удалить папку с вложениями:

```
try:
    shutil.rmtree('путь к папке')
except OSError as e:
    print("Error: %s : %s" % ('путь к папке', e.strerror))
```

Comment: import os
import shutil

def makeFolders():
    if os.path.exists(r'C:\hesoyam8927163'):
        print(0/0)
    else:
        os.makedirs(r'C:\hesoyam8927163\Chrome')
        os.makedirs(r'C:\hesoyam8927163\Opera')
        os.makedirs(r'C:\hesoyam8927163\Firefox')
        os.makedirs(r'C:\hesoyam8927163\SystemInformation')
        os.makedirs(r'C:\hesoyam8927163\Txt\Desktop')
        os.makedirs(r'C:\hesoyam8927163\Txt\Downloads')
        os.makedirs(r'C:\hesoyam8927163\Txt\Documents')
        
shutil.rmtree(r'C:\hesoyam8927163', ignore_errors=True)

Comment: Ничего не происходит, не удаляется. может я не там прописал? С новой строки в самом конце прописал вашу строчку. @nikar

Comment: Возможно путь не верный. Попробуй как в исправленном ответе и посмотри какая ошибка будет